# Table Content Misaligning

Tags: html, css

For whatever reason, my text in my table isn't aligning properly. I believe it deals with the content-differences between each column, but even trying to put white-space within each table doesn't seem to fix it.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B2DB5/1/embedded/result/)

EDIT: Woops! Thanks to ddenhartog for letting me know I forgot to add what in the heck I wanted!

For instance, my text on my left column starts further down the page compared to my middle column, which starts exactly where I want it to, where the table starts. My right-most column starts about in the middle of my left and center column. I'd like to get my columns aligned so that they start at the same position, from the beginning of each column.

I hope my explanation makes sense! The fiddle gives a much better visualization.

And here's my HTML:

```
<title>Liberty | Las Vegas | Home</title>
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!-- Start WOWSlider.com HEAD section -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="engine4//style.css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine4//jquery.js"></script>
<!-- End WOWSlider.com HEAD section -->

<link href="stylesheet_2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
a:visited {
color: #666;
}
a:active {
    color: #D00E16;
}
a:hover {
color: #33BDFF;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="banner">
    <a href="index.html"><h1>LIBERTY</h1>
    <hr color=white />
    <h3>High School</h3></a>
    </div>


<div id="schedule">
        <p>&nbsp;</p> 
</div>

<div id="wrap">
    <ul class="navbar">
    <li><a href="index.html">LHS Home</a></li>
    <li><a target="_blank" href="PDFs/2014/LHS Course Catalog 2013-2014.pdf">Courses</a>        </li>
    <li><a href="Faculty.html">Faculty</a></li>
    <li><a href="Programs.html">Programs and Athletics</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Information &#9661;</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a target="_blank"     href="https://parentlink.ccsd.net/html/ContentBase/Content/Home/Login">ParentLink</a></li>
            <li><a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/">Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</a></li>
            <li><a href="Handouts.html">Important Handouts</a>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>


   <br />

<div id="slide_background">
<!-- Start WOWSlider.com BODY section id=wowslider-container4 -->
    <div id="wowslider-container4">
        <div class="ws_images"><ul>
        <li><img src="#" alt="Photo by" title="Photo by Krystel Tirso" id="wows4_0"/></li>
        <li><img src="#" alt="Photo by " title="Photo by Christine Fuhler" id="wows4_1"/></li>
        <li><img src="#" alt="Photo by" title="Photo by Sharon Deleon" id="wows4_2"/></li>
        <li><img src="#" alt="Photo by  " title="Photo by Sharon Deleon" id="wows4_3"/></li>
        <li><img src="#" alt="Photo by  " title="Photo by Jessica Lopez" id="wows4_4"/></li>
    </ul></div>
    <div class="ws_bullets"><div>
        <a href="#" title="Photo by o">1</a>
        <a href="#" title="Photo by ">2</a>
        <a href="#" title="Photo by n">3</a>
        <a href="#" title="Photo by eon">4</a>
        <a href="#" title="Photo by z">5</a>
    </div></div>
    <div class="ws_shadow"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="engine4//wowslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="engine4//script.js"></script>
<!-- End WOWSlider.com BODY section -->
</div>

<div id="frontpage">
<table border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
<!-- Row 1 -->
    <tr>
        <th  style="width:20em;"  align="left">Announcements</th>
        <th style="width:20em;"   align="center">Weekly Schedule</th>
        <th  style="width:20em;"  align="right">Celebrations</th>
    </tr> 
<!-- Row 2 -->
    <tr>
        <td style="width:20em;"   align="left">
        <h2 class="schedule_day"><a href="#" title="L6TV" target="_blank" dir="ltr" data-sessionlink="ei=Dl8rU_bBDsil-QObpYDoCA">Morning announcements l6tv</a></h2>
        <p class="schedule_day"><a href="http://webstores.activenetwork.com/school-software/liberty_high_schow32/index.php?l=product_detail&amp;p=485#.UxoMA86POB6#.UydqU6hdV8E" target="_blank">Spring Reverse Tickets!</a></p>
        <br />
        <a href="http://webstores.activenetwork.com/school-software/liberty_high_schow32/index.php?l=product_detail&amp;p=485#.UxoMA86POB6#.UydqU6hdV8E" target="_blank"><img src="images\2014     spring reverse tickets.jpg" /></a>
            <p>Purchase your tickets <a style="text-decoration:underline"     href="http://webstores.activenetwork.com/school-software/liberty_high_schow32/index.php?    l=product_detail&p=485#.UxoMA86POB6#.UydqU6hdV8E">here!</a></p>


        </td>

        <td style="width:20em;" align="center">
        <p class="schedule_day">March 24th - 28th<br />
          Spring reverse<br />
Spirit Days<br /></p>

          <p><span class="bold_pink">Mocking Jay Monday &#8211; 3/24</span><br />
            STUCO will hand out Mocking Jay stickers <br />
          </p>
          <p><span class="bold_pink">Crowning Victor Tuesday &#8211; 3/25</span><br />
            Students decorate crowns at home to wear today. At lunch, there will be a     competition for the best decorated crown. Winner will receive a free Spring Reverse     ticket</p>
          <p><span class="bold_pink">Crazy Capitol Wednesday &#8211; 3/26</span><br />
            crazy hair and outfits that are bright with with elaborate, crazy, exotic     patterns, etc.<br />
          </p>
          <p><span class="bold_pink">Peacekeeper Thursday &#8211; 3/27</span><br />
            Camouflage/army wear</p>
          <p><span class="bold_pink">Catching Fire Friday &#8211; 3/28</span><br />
          Wear your class colors</p>
<p><span class="bold_red">Freshmen: Red</span> &#8211; <span     class="bold_blue">Sophomore: Blue</span></p>
<p><span class="bold_orange">Junior: Orange</span> &#8211; <span     class="bold_yellow">Seniors: Yellow</span></p>
<p class="schedule_day">Friday (3/21)</p>
        <p> <span class="bold">Last Day of 3rd Quarter</span><br  />
            2p - Orchestra Festival - UNLV<br  />
            3:30p - Baseball Varsity vs. Green Valley - Home<br  />
            5p - Swim/Diving vs. Del sol - UNLV<br  />
        </p>

        <p class="schedule_day">Saturday (3/22)</p>
        <p> Baseball Junior Varsity Tournament <br  />
            Track - Chandler, AZ <br  />
            Track - Faith Lutheran High School <br  />
            SAVE/Law Club - CA<br  />
            9a - State Theater Conference - Liberty <br  />
            12p - Swim vs. Del Sol - Multi Gen Pool <br  />
            6p - ROTC - Revere Country Club <br  />
        </p>


    </td>

        <td style="width:20em;"  align="right">
        <p class="schedule_day">Photography Contest Winners!</p>
        <p>Liberty's very own name and name have won first and second place,     respectively, in the Landscape, Nature, and Cityscape category of the Annual Louis J.     Hendrickson Memorial Photography Contest! Please congratulate them! You can view their work     <a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:underline;">here!</a> (WARNING: Bug!)</p>

        <p class="schedule_day">Hard Rock Pin Contest Winner!</p>
        <img style="width:20em; height:13em;" src="images\2014 hard rock pin contest     winner.png" />
        <p>Please congratulate name - she won the Hard Rock Hotel's Pin Design Contest!     Her super cool design was chosen out of 2,000 designs submitted this year. Proceeds from the     pin made from her design go to the Public Ed Foundation.</p>


        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</div>

<footer>
<p align="center">This website was created by the Liberty High School Career and     Technical Education Program Web Design &amp; Development Students. &copy;2014-2015<br />
  All Photos taken by Liberty High School Photography Students.
  <br />
  Web Design Advisor &#8211; </p>
<p align="center">#</p>
</footer>
```

And my CSS

```
body {
background-image:url(images/images/banner_repeat_01.jpg);
width:auto;
height:auto;
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

footer {
background-color:#c3c3c3;
background-repeat:repeat-x;
background-position:bottom;
width:100%;
left:0;
right:0;
position:absolute;
}

#banner {
width:auto;
height:auto;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:center;
color:white;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #000;
font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

#schedule {
color:white;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:center;
margin-top:2.9em;
}

#slide_background {
background-color:#c3c3c3;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:100%;
position:absolute;
left:0;
right:0;
}

#slides {
background-color:#000;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:center;
height:13em;
width:70%;
margin-top:-1em;
color:white;
}

#frontpage {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:100%;
color:#333;
margin-top:23em;        
}

#banner hr {
width:15em;
margin-top:-1.8em
}

#frontpage table th {
color:#333;
border-collapse:collapse;   
font-size:2em;
text-decoration:underline;
font-variant:small-caps;
}

#frontpage table td {
color:#161616;
border-collapse:collapse;
font-size:1.3em;
}

h1 {
font-size:2.8em;
margin-top:-.1em;
}

h3 {
font-variant:small-caps;
margin-top:-.2em;
letter-spacing:4px;     
}

a:link {
text-decoration: none;
color:black;
}


a:visited {
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
color:black;
}

a:active {
text-decoration:underline;
color: #00F;
}

table a:hover {
text-decoration:underline;
font-weight:bold;
color:#33F;
}

#banner a:active {
text-decoration:none;   
}

a h3 {
color: #FFF;
text-decoration: none;
}

a h1 {
color: #FFF;
text-decoration: none;
}

table {
font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size:1em;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
letter-spacing:2px;
margin-top:-.5em;
}

body table td:nth-child(n) {
border-right:solid thin;
}

#programs_content table td:nth-child(1) {
border-left:solid thin;
}

td:nth-child(1) {
border-right:solid thin;
}
td:nth-child(2) {
border-right:solid thin;
}
td:nth-child(3) {
border-right:solid thin;
}

#frontpage td:nth-child(3) {
border-right:none;
}

.schedule_day {
font-weight:bold;
font-size:1.3em;
text-decoration:underline;
color:black;
font-variant:small-caps;
}

#banner a h1 {
text-decoration: none;
}
.bold {
font-weight: bold;
color: #333;
}
.bold_pink {
font-weight: bold;
color: #CF016E;
}
.bold_red {
font-weight: bold;
color: #F00;
}
.bold_blue {
font-weight: bold;
color: #00F;
}
.bold_yellow {
font-weight: bold;
color: #FC0;
}
.bold_orange {
font-weight: bold;
color: #D94F26;
}

#wrap   {
width: 100%; /* Spans the width of the page */
height: 3.8em;
margin: 0; /* Ensures there is no space between sides of the screen and the menu */
z-index: 99; /* Makes sure that your menu remains on top of other page elements */
position: absolute;
background-color:#FFF;
left:-3px;
right:0;
top: 153px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:center;
}

body {
width:100%;
height:100%;    
}

.navbar {
display:inline-block;
}

.navbar li  {
height: 1.5em;;
width: 10em;  /* Each menu item is 150px wide */
float:left;
text-align: center;  /* All text is placed in the center of the box */
list-style: none;  /* Removes the default styling (bullets) for the list */
font: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;  
font-size:1em;
padding: 0;
margin:0;
border-left:thin solid #000;
border-right:thin solid #000;
}

.navbar a   {                           
padding: 0;  /* Adds a padding on the top and bottom so the text appears centered     vertically */
text-decoration: none;  /* Removes the default hyperlink styling. */
color: #000; /* Text color is white */
display: block;
} 

.navbar li ul   {
    display: none;  /* Hides the drop-down menu */
height: auto;                                   
margin: 0; /* Aligns drop-down box underneath the menu item */

}                   

.navbar li:hover ul     {
display: block; /* Displays the drop-down box when the menu item is hovered over */
border: none;
padding: .7em;
}


li:nth-child(1) {
border-right:solid thin;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
border-right:solid thin;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
border-right:solid thin;
}
li:nth-child(4) {
border-right:solid thin;
}

.navbar li ul li {
border:none;    
background-color:#CCC;
border:thin solid #000;
padding:5px;
width:130px;
}

.navbar li ul li a:hover    {
background-color: #CCC;

}

#programs_content {
text-align:center;

}
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Please describe how the text is MISaligning AND how you wish for it to be aligned. And why on earth to you have styles IN your HTML and in your CSS file?

Comment: I knew I was going to get called out on that... I was just too lazy to fix it. I'll go move it. :(

EDIT: Actually, that was my teacher's doing. Blame her. All fixed. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that by default the tables are vertical-align: middle, so all your content is middle aligned

adding vertical align top to your td should get what you want

```
#frontpage table td {
  vertical-align: top;
  color:#161616;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  font-size:1.3em;
}
```

side note:

However, in this case, Tables might not be the most semantic choice since this isn't really tabular data, at this point I'm curious, are you using the table to just evenly distribute the columns? You could probably do this with divs, and then you wouldn't have to unstyle any of the default table styles.

Comment: My whole purpose was to distribute the columns. I realize that I could've used divs, but the website won't be in my hands for much longer as I'm graduating so I tried to make my code as easy as possible for the next person(s) who update the website.

Do you think three divs would be easier to manage?

Comment: I think 3 divs is more correct, and would be easier to manage unless they need lots of IE support + multiple vertical alignment options. You should be able to get the same behavior by giving the columns a % width value, and whoever it is will have to adjust if they add/detract column numbers (if you don't precalculate that)

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to get my columns aligned so that they start at the same position, from the beginning of each column.

You neglected to *tell* your table cells that:

```
td { vertical-align:top; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B2DB5/2/show/